# Any way to program a robot remotely?

Tags: robotic-arm, c++, kuka, kit

So Udacity, Kuka and KIT are/were offering a Kuka challenge.  Basically, the participants got to write code and run it remotely on a Kuka robot based in the KIT labs in Germany and submit their code as part of the challenge.  However, this is only available to U.S. residents.  Here is the [link](https://www.udacity.com/kuka-robotics-challenge) to those that might be interested:

My question is that, are there other programs or initiatives like this where a person can write and run code on a robot?  I know it can be done with simulators but I want to know if these initiatives exist outside of Udacity